# document.getElementById() in Angular Application

Tags: angular

I found this: `this.toastElement = document.getElementById('toh-toast');` in the official Angular styleguide but couldn´t believe this is the way to go.

So I want to modify the style of an HTML element by clicking on a button. My first approach was to use `[ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}"` on the HTML-Element. According to the styleguide I can also use `this.toasElement.style.max-width = "10";`

Link to the styleguide article: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#member-sequence

Which one is the correct way?

Comment: The reason behind that approach, imo, is to access global elements that doesn't belong to the current component (like a toast, or a dialog)

Comment: I have seen somewhere that it's no more discouraged to directly reference DOM element in Angular but personally would avoid as much as it's possible :)

Comment: use directive ngStyle